# docker start: no space left on device

Tags: docker, centos

I found one of my containers down. It is the second time I have this problem. When I try to bring it up with docker start I get:

> Error response from daemon: invalid header field value "oci runtime
>   error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused
>   \"process_linux.go:359: container init caused \\"rootfs_linux.go:89:
>   jailing process inside rootfs caused \\\\"can't create pivot_root
>   dir , error mkdir
>   /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/da2101d43e6c8200eb22a4415b0aedf8033c7c701a19392217b8947738a723bf/rootfs/.pivot_root592021975:
>   no space left on device\\\\"\\"\"\n" Error: failed to start
>   containers: mydockername

Any idea why I am getting this no space left on device? Host volume is only 6% occupation.

I am using CentOS Docker version 1.12.3, build 6b644ec

Comment: Hello, could you please paste the result of `df -h`? Also, could you please test with another image?

Comment: What is the host os? what is the command that you use to start / run the image?

Comment: Hello, I use centos-release-7-2.1511.el7.centos.2.10.x86_64 (virtualised in a hosting provider). Sorry Carlos, I can't do df -h. I needed to put the service back so I deleted the corrupted server and created it.

Comment: Rao, I use a simple docker run... without any special frag... I just use -d --name -m --link flags (I link it to a database in other docker).

Comment: Did you find a solution to this in the end?

Comment: Sorry I didn't. I am not sure why this occurs... I can't think why the docker shows that "no space left on device" error as the device has no limit and the app only performs a small writing to logs.

Answer (score 2):

Disk space of container is limited, not the host space. Default limit of container disk space is 10G. If docker storage is devicemapper, can mount the container filesystem and delete some logs. Then you can start the container.

```
~# docker start centos3_50_pay
```

> Error response from daemon: invalid header field value "oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:359: container init caused "rootfs_linux.go:89: jailing process inside rootfs caused "can't create pivot_root dir , error mkdir /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/96fd436942ce6c9a618ccea9c52f5e9b766065db9e7edf870967b27fbaf3f9bf/rootfs/.pivot_root558329180: no space left on device"
>
> Error: failed to start containers: centos3_50_pay

```
~# docker inspect centos3_50_pay | grep Device  
        "Devices": [],
            "DeviceId": "467",
            "DeviceName": "docker-253:0-3222880762-96fd436942ce6c9a618ccea9c52f5e9b766065db9e7edf870967b27fbaf3f9bf",
            "DeviceSize": "10737418240"

~# cat /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/metadata/ \
       96fd436942ce6c9a618ccea9c52f5e9b766065db9e7edf870967b27fbaf3f9bf
{"device_id":467,"size":10737418240,"transaction_id":736,\
 "initialized":false,"deleted":false}

~# echo "10737418240/512" |bc
 20971520
~# dmsetup ls
 docker-thinpool (253:5)                           

~# dmsetup create tmp --table "0 20971520 thin /dev/mapper/ \
    docker-thinpool 467"
~# mount /dev/mapper/tmp /root/tmp
~# cd /root/tmp/rootfs/
~# ll
~# umount /root/tmp
~# dmsetup remove tmp
~# docker start centos3_50_pay
 centos3_50_pay
```

Answer (score 1):

on MAC OSX, this will help you out, deleting old, obsolete stuff:

```
docker rm $(docker ps -q -f status=exited)
docker rmi $(docker images -q -f dangling=true)
docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -qf dangling=true)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you use single quotes, double quotes, and no quotes for the query part of the three commands?

Comment: no quotes are required, 10x for the tip. fixed.